# "Firefox webdriver could not be verified for use in Firefox and has been disabled"

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

Since Firefox updated to version 43, I get the following message when trying to run an application using Webdriver: "Firefox webdriver could not be verified for use in Firefox and has been disabled".  I have already toggled xpinstall.signatures.required to false to deal with the problem with unsigned extensions so this may not be the issue.  Any suggestions for making webdriver work with Firefox?

Comment: Did you update Selenium?

Comment: What selenium version you are using, if this is old one then you should update.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and it got fixed when updated selenium to 2.48.2 . 
You need to use latest selenium to work with Firefox 43.0.3.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just updated selenium and it has fixed the problem.

Comment: How do I update selenium? I've changed the selenium version in my POM to use 2.48.2 but if I check firefox extensions while running a selenium test it is still using version 2.46.

Comment: It seems you haven't yet removed the previous version of jar file. please remove it from the references and retry.